# How to find the probability of that the bag ran out of specific balls (for example, red) earlier than other balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The rules of the final round of King's Lottery in Byteland are simple:

The player starts to draw balls from an opaque bag containing $a$ red balls, $b$ green balls and $c$ blue balls initially.
After the player draws the ball, the ball is not returned into the bag.
The player continues the process until he collects all $a$ red balls, or all $b$ green balls, or all $c$ blue balls.
The player wins the Gold Jackpot if he collects $a$ red balls, Silver Jackpot if he collects $b$ green balls, or Bronze Jackpot otherwise. Given $a$,$b$ and $c$, calculate the probabilities of winning each jackpot.
For example:

$a=1,b=2,c=3$,then $P(G)=\frac{7}{12},P(S)=\frac{4}{15},P(B)=\frac{3}{20}$

$a=1,b=1,c=1$,then $P(G)=\frac{1}{3},P(S)=\frac{1}{3},P(B)=\frac{1}{3}$

**My attempt**

I tried several times to solve this question. I think that I should common outcomes- all different arrangement of balls drawn from the bag and I calculated with repetition of permutation formaula: $\frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!b!c!}$. It determines denominator of fraction of probability.

**Need to help**

I couldn't find desired outcomes (numerator of fraction). How to find the number of desired outcomes that the bag ran out of specific balls (for example, red) earlier than other balls?

Comment: [1] What is the source of the question ? [2] Where are you stuck ? [3] You must  enter whatever efforts you have made

Comment: Hint:  If there were only two colors of ball the prize would only depend on the last ball.

Comment: @trueblueanil Problem source link below:
https://www.eolymp.com/en/problems/11316
I cannot find general formula for this problem, I tried a lot but didn't find formula, please help me simplified formula to handle this problem.

Comment: If you had shown *some* effort, even if fumbling, help could have been given, but protocol doesn't allow answers on no effort shown questions

Comment: @trueblueanil I had effort, I found the common outcomes, but I couldn't find the number of desired outcomes.

Comment: Please don't put clarifications and additional information into the comments.  Instead, revise your post so that it incorporates all relevant information and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Part of our purpose is to build up a knowledge archive that will be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the probabilities have been given in terms of gold, silver and bronze, we might as well replace the colors by $1$ gold medal, $2$ silver medals and $3$ bronze medals randomly arranged in a row.

Working out for $a=1,b=2,c=3$ will be enough to get the formula

- To get the desired result for the gold medal, the three medals must *survive* longer either in the order $SBG$ or $BSG$.
- Consider the sequence $SBG\;$. P($S$ survives max)  = P($S$ drawn last) = P($S$ *put* first)$=\frac{b}{a+b+c}$
- Having computed the survival probability of $S$, to compute the survival probability of the next medal, $B$ *we just imagine that silver medals have vanished from the   row*, so again we have only two types to deal with and compute in a similar way !
- Thus P($S$ survives longest followed by $B$) $=\frac{b}{a+b+c}\cdot \frac{c}{a+c} = \frac26\frac34 = \frac14 =  X\;$ (say)
  and ($B$ survives longest followed by $S$) $= \frac{c}{a+b+c}\cdot\frac{b}{b+c}  
  = \frac{3}{6}\frac23 = \frac13 = Y$(say)
- Finally, P(gold is first to "die") $=X+Y = \frac14 + \frac13 = \frac{7}{12}$
- The values for silver and bronze can be computed analogously.

Comment: You were finding it not able to proceed, and were at a dead end. Doresn't this solve your difficulty ?

Comment: What a great solution! Thank you very much, this solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to have been of help ! $\;\;$ :)